# maxlength attribute is not restricting characters to 250

Tags: php, html

- I have provided maxlength=250 attribute to html textarea input.
- That doesn't allow me to type more than 250 characters.
- But the problem is when I copy paste data from other site in my
  textarea  and that data has two "\n".
- Then this will show the count to 250 but In a server    side in my
  php code the length is 254 and It is breaking my code

  < textarea maxlength="250" >

And Input data is :

"PSTD usually lasts up to six months. Yet, there are cases where it lingers on and requires treatment for some particular types of symptoms or behavioural changes.

Treatment for PSTD:

Mindfulness meditation (not a treatment option) helps in recogniz"

If you put this data in text area It will allowed by textarea but when you submit form and inside PHP it will throw error that more than 500 characters not allowed.

Any solution for that ?? I don't want to trim \n from text ...

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that specific question (a pre-HTML5 question about the attribute not working at all). Despite the misleading title I think he's just asking about `\r\n` vs `\n`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks :)